# GridSearchCV giving " __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_topics'" error

Tags: python, lda, gridsearchcv

I am running the following piece of code in a google collab notebook. I have already researched this type of error and made sure to update my version of sklearn prior to 0.24.dev0 but the error keeps happening. Can anyone help?

```
search_params = {'n_components': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 'learning_decay': [.5, .7, .9]}

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(max_iter=5, learning_method='online', learning_offset=50.,random_state=0)

model = GridSearchCV(lda, param_grid=search_params)

model.fit(data_vectorized)

GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
       estimator=LatentDirichletAllocation(batch_size=128, doc_topic_prior=None,
             evaluate_every=-1, learning_decay=0.7, learning_method=None,
             learning_offset=10.0, max_doc_update_iter=100, max_iter=10,
             mean_change_tol=0.001, n_components=10, n_jobs=1,
             n_topics=None, perp_tol=0.1, random_state=None,
             topic_word_prior=None, total_samples=1000000.0, verbose=0),
       fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=1,
       param_grid={'n_topics': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 'learning_decay': [0.5, 0.7, 0.9]},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html):

Changed in version 0.19: `n_topics` was renamed to `n_components`

It looks like all versions >=0.19 keep this change (I checked 0.23)

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. I renamed n_topics to n_components and now I get this error: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params'"

Comment: That's actually ok. You solved the first problem. Go to the link provided in my answer and check that you are using the right parameter/argument names. You will get this solved in minutes!

Comment: You are correct! got it to work. Thank you so much for your help!